# WordPress Wedding RSVP using Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am building my wedding website and want to integrate an RSVP form using Gravity Forms. The issue I am running into is how to set certain guest that have +1's. I would like to show an additional guest entry (First Name, Last Name, Meal Option) when the initial First Name and Last Name has been populated. How would I go about doing this? Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the hip: a db lookup with a get request ie "site.com/rsvp?ph=phonenumber" and the page looks up the phone number as a unique identifier (so all your John Smiths get a unique row) that will show +1 or not. Either that or 2 pages, one with the +1 and one without and send it appropriately.

Comment: @Joshua Thanks for the reply! I don't think I would need the phone number. Could I use a name instead? Are there any guides on how to do a database lookup with a get request?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd solve this problem:

First, you need to put everything in the DB, the easiest way would be to either do it manually or somehow loop through an array/CSV calling [add_option($key, $value)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) Again, I would recommend a mobile/phone number as they'll be unique so you don't pull the wrong "John Smith". I'll assume you'll keep it basic with `$key` as the unique identifier and `$value` as `boolean` as to whether to show additional info. Interestingly, by default, if not found [get_option($key)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) will return `false` and therefore not show your additional data, which I would assume you'd want anyway. If you'd rather it return `true` just pass `true` as the second argument.

Now for your answer:

Your URL is something like `https://somesite.com/rsvp?id=1234`.

```
function allowed_plus_one() {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $allowed = get_option($id);
    return $allowed;
}
```

Then assumedly it'll be something like

```
if (allowed_plus_one()) {
    // show form with plus one
} else {
    // show form without
}
```

EDIT:

Keeping separate incase this has already been viewed.

You should also be checking for the existence of $_GET["id"] and behaving accordingly. eg:

```
if (isset($_GET["id"] && !empty($_GET["id"]) {
    //do logic above
} else {
   //here by mistake so don't show any form?
}
```

Comment: You could turn the functio into a one-liner like so `if (get_option($_GET["id")) {` ...